# SQL Join with Multiple User IDs

Tags: sql, join

I have a table with each row containing two user ids. There is a user id for the person who created the post and a user id for the person who last edited the post.

I want to join the each user id to a user table in order to pull in the name of each person. I can do that. However, how do I return the name of each person separately?

I would like the "Created Name" and "Edited Name". Each drawing from the user table.

Thank you

Comment: Use two different table aliases for your USER table for two `JOIN` statements.

Comment: do you have an example of what that would look like? Thank you

Comment: Im pulling in the name from the same table so how would you know to alias when returning user name. Because they're are two joins to the same table how would you select a different value based on the source tables column?

Comment: Because you join the same table twice, each time with a different alias.

Comment: Please see the voting arrow mouseover texts & show what you can do with a [mcve]. Please clarify via post edits, not comments.

Answer (score 2):

Two joins should do the work:

```
select
  p.*,
  c.name as creator_name,
  e.name as editor_name
from post p
join user c on p.creator_id = c.id
join user e on p.editor_id = e.id
```

Comment: That is assuming that there are two different columns for the user. The users all reside in one column. Does that make sense?

Comment: If each post records the user who created it **and** the user who edited it, then yes, you need two columns (I named them `creator_id` and `editor_id`).

Comment: ohhh I think I get it